# Which languages are supported by reCAPTCHA?

Tags: google, language, captcha

The [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/customization.html) states that `"Any supported language code."` is supported, but then says:

> Which language is used in the interface for the pre-defined themes. The following languages are supported:
>    - English  en
>    - Dutch    nl
>    - French   fr
>    - German   de
>    - Portuguese   pt
>    - Russian  ru
>    - Spanish  es
>    - Turkish  tr
>
> If the language of your site isn't supported, you can always use custom theming to put reCAPTCHA in your language.

- If the first statement is meant to mean:

  - *Any language*. It  isn't true because Japan (ja/jp/jpn) isn't supported as far as I can see.  (Plus then, the last statement disproves the first one.)
  - Languages in the list (above), then what about Italian? "it" is supported but not in the list.

### So which languages are actually supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pre-defined:

#### Completely supported:

- English

#### Partially supported:

- Dutch
- French
- German
- Portuguese
- Russian
- Spanish
- Turkish

*"play sound again", "download sound as MP3", and entire manual (JavaScript-independent) challenge in English*.

#### Barely supported:

- Italian

*"play sound again", "download sound as MP3", entire manual (JavaScript-independent) challenge, **plus** audio challenge &=and help popup in English*.

---

## Custom Translations:

Custom translations can be written for any language, but the audio challenge, help popup, and manual (JavaScript-independent) challenge will always be in English.

The custom translations are defined using Javascript that's why they won't work when the manual challenge is being used. Note: The manual challenge is displayed in an iframe (can't edit it) and includes the following text (always in English):

> "We need to make sure you are a human. Please solve the challenge below, and click the I'm a Human button to get a confirmation code. To make this process easier in the future, we recommend you enable Javascript"

---

*Note: Latin/Roman alphabet is the only supported alphabet.*

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

It would appear that any language is supported but only the mentioned languages have pre-defined themes and if you want to use any other language you would have to write your own customisation.

Comment: That is so stupid (of Google). Of course it is supported if I supply the text and it's displayed unparsed; any text is supported. I could put in "abcdefg" for "Incorrect. Try again" and it won't complain.